# iPhone-CTMessageCenter API

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, iphone-privateapi

I have an application to schedule and send an SMS to an individual or bulk in iPhone. So, I am planning to use a Private API called `CTMessageCenter`. But, I am getting to know that Apple might reject the app during their acceptance, if we use the above third party API.

Also, I am getting to know that if I use the API provided by Apple, then that would be accepted for sure.

Can you help me answering this question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. If you use any private Apple API in your app, it will be rejected.

Note that a third party code library is not the same thing as a private API (such as libraries you download from github, sourceForge, etc.) As long as the library(s) you use follow the rules, that is fine.

I'm not familiar with CTMessageCenter, so I don't know which it is.